# What does "can/could shake a baguette at" mean?

Tags: idioms, idiom-meaning

Could you please explain me what does "can/could shake a baguette at" mean?

> More fromage than you **can shake a baguette at**.

or

> There were robot barbers, picturephones, and more flying machines than
>   you **could shake a baguette at**.

or

> It took a glossy US reboot for Battlestar Galactica to turn the Cylons
>   from villains to protagonists with more existential issues than
>   Jean-Paul Sartre **could shake a baguette at**.

Comment: "The phrase "shake a baguette at" is a play on the common English idiomatic phrase/cliche "more X than you can [or _could_] shake a stick at." The joke is that a baguette is long and thin so it looks a bit like a golden-brown stick. But the joke works better with the fromage [cheese] and Sartre intros than with the robot intro, because _fromage_ (like _baguette_) is a French word and Sartre (like _baguette_) is best enjoyed with a large bowl of strong black coffee.

Comment: it's quite funny that apparently a couple of people have now, made that "modified humorous cliché", in the same way, going to baguette, apparently unrelated.

Comment: Sven is very astute that the fromage-related one works better: the baguetteness is natural there.  In the latter, it's somewhat ex-nihilo; it's two (perhaps three) steps away, not one.

Comment: I wonder if the second quote was a description of a French book or movie.  That would make the "baguette" phrase more natural.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a word play on the English idiom **[more XX than you could shake a stick at](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/more+than+can+shake+a+stick+at)**, trying to put a pseudo-French  (or "mock" French) twist on the phrase. The joke being that a baguette resembles, somewhat, a stick (or at least a baton or a club.)

(The Free Dictionary)

Comment: From "Online Etymology": **baguette** - _from Italian bacchetta, literally "a small rod," diminutive of bacchio "rod," from Latin baculum "a stick" (see bacillus). ... "a long, thin loaf of French bread" is from 1958_. So indeed, "a stick"

Comment: Brian, one point.  When you take "shake a stick at!" and replace the stick with anything, to make it more funny for your specific situation: it seems to me that often there is no relation at all to stickness (long, thin, etc).  You just take something "relating stupidly" to the first thing, and use that as the second thing. More beer than you can shake an Australian at, more mosquitoes than you could shake a swamp at, and so on. This seems pretty commonplace. For me it's more just a bonus that (in this case), baguettes are stickish. (Actually I didn't notice that at all upon first glance.)